# ttk.Widget.state() TclError: Invalid state name

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I try change ttk.button state (at the beggining of mainloop) in tkinter like in this [manual](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Widget.html) [actualization: actually [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-state-spec.html).]

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.map("C.TButton",
    foreground=[('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'blue')],
    background=[('pressed', '!disabled', 'black'), ('active', 'white')]
    )

colored_btn = ttk.Button(text="Test", style="C.TButton")
colored_btn.pack()

colored_btn.state('pressed')

root.mainloop()
```

Result in error:

```
in state return self.tk.splitlist(str(self.tk.call(self._w, "state", statespec))) _tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name p
```

Comment: The link in your question doesn't work.

Comment: I refreshed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
colored_btn.state(('pressed',))
```

From [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tkinter.ttk.html?highlight=ttk%20style#tkinter.ttk.Widget.state):

> statespec will usually be a list or a tuple.

I suppose this issue comes from 8.6 vs 8.5 tkinter version difference.

Take notice that in manual linked in question (tkinter 8.5) there is `stateSpac` argument and in tkinter 8.6 - `statespec`. Such things should always warn you that there may be changing in versions.

Comment: In my opinion "usually" is silly statement for manual reference

Comment: Actulaly any iterable will do.